# C++ evaluation order and possible outcome

Tags: c++, pre-increment

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << ++i << ' ' << --i << std::endl;
}
```

In his "C++17 The Complete Guide" book Nicolai Josuttis writes that **before** C++17 this particular example might produce unpredictable results. Both `1 0` and `0 1` might be produced but what's more `0 0` is also a possible output. I don't get why the third sequence should be considered as possible. Either `++i` or `--i` should be evaluated before the second value is evaluated which by definition cannot produce two zeros, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Amolgorithm That's pre-increment, not post-increment if you really want to add such tags.

Comment: Absolutley just a guess: four things are happening, take the value of i, incriment i, take the value of i, decrement i. I don't think the order of *any* of those things is defined - so while it does seem likely that they would *at least* happen in pairs, I think a "correct" C+++ compiler is allowed to do them in truly any order, even take the value of i twice first.

Comment: The evaluation order of sub-expressions in between `<<` is not defined.

Comment: Replace `++i` with "increment `i`, read `i`", same for `--i`, then do as follows: increment `i`, decrement `i`, read `i`, read `i`. Then remove increment-decrement as an optimization if you're up to it. There were no guarantees that sub-expressions and their side effects are not interleaved. Fun effects are still possible with C++17, though, but require more convoluted examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before C++17, the `0 0` outcome was possible roughly like this.

1. `++i` is evaluated. `i` now stores `1`. The result of this expression (which, importantly, is an l-value reference to `i`, not the r-value `1`) is set aside as an argument to the `<<` operator.
2. `--i` is evaluated. `i` now stores `0`. The result of this expression (which, importantly, is an l-value reference to `i`, not the r-value `0`) is set aside as an argument to the `<<` operator.
3. `<<` operators are evaluated, where both arguments are references to `i` which has value `0`.